Почему после присоединительного союза НО перед деепричастным оборотом нужно обязательно ставить запятую?
Меня всегда удивляет обязательность какого-либо знака: неужели так уж всегда? Конечно, в центре внимания именно спорный союз НО.
Союзу НО категорически ЗАПРЕЩЕНО соединяться с обособленным деепричастным оборотом, а с придаточным предложением позволено иметь варианты в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия паузы при чтении.
Так почему же так?  Давайте наконец научимся думать, а не только следовать правилам.
Простейший пример: Но(,) зная это, трудно поверить его словам.  Неужели будем обязательно ставить запятую, обособляя оборот. Как на практике ставятся знаки в нераспространенных предложениях? Хотя на практику трудно в полной мере ориентироваться. Корректорам, разумеется, удобнее ставить знаки по правилам.
Мое мнение:
Присоединительные союзы относятся ко всему предложению, и они считаются таковыми по отношению к предыдущему тексту. И если мы обособляем деепричастный оборот, то это уже проблемы этого оборота, который мы хотим или не хотим сделать вставкой. Аналогично по отношению к придаточному.
Предлагаю обсудить этот очень конкретный вопрос. Он в достаточной мере значим для практики письма.
Примечание. Меня особенно огорчают всякого рода перестановки при анализе. Союз относится ко всему предложению и стоит в его начале, так что не надо его переставлять))  Тема обсуждалась на форуме бесконечное количество раз, поэтому утомила эта "манная каша на тарелке" при наших обсуждениях. Запрещено? Тогда ссылка на правило Розенталя и короткий ответ. Информативность стиля! Зачем больше-то?)
Розенталь § 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов, пункт 5 (примечание)
 Примечание. Для различных случаев употребления 
 присоединительного союза в самом начале 
 предложения устанавливаются следующие правила:

 1) если за союзом следует обособленный оборот 
 (чаще всего — конструкция с деепричастием), 
 запятая ставится после союзов и и но и не ставится 
 после союза а: И, задержавшись у выхода, он 
 обернулся; Но, не желая возвращаться к сказанному, 
 докладчик это место своего сообщения пропустил; А 
 услышав эти слова, он воскликнул…; [См. § 20.]

 2) после присоединительного союза, если дальше 
 следует вводное слово (сочетание, предложение), 
 запятая, как правило, не ставится: И вероятно, вы 
 его не дождётесь; Но может быть, вопрос ещё не 
 рассматривался; А впрочем, и этот вариант 
 приемлем; И представьте себе, случайный ответ 
 оказался верным; [См. § 25, п. 6.]

 3) перед придаточной частью запятая ставится в 
 зависимости от значения присоединительного союза и 
 наличия/отсутствия паузы при чтении. [См. § 36, п. 
 5.]


Sharon, пожелания по оформлению. Вы в последнее время пользуетесь серым фоном, а почему? На нём невозможно ничего выделить, сделать так, как в цитируемом тексте. Когда хотите сделать жирным, вместо этого появляются звёздочки. Или вот здесь, например, совсем некрасиво выглядит: "...запятая ставится после союзов и и но и не ставится после союза а..." // И вопрос по делу. Мне непонятно, почему в правилах пишут о союзах в самом начале предложения (после точки). Такие же конструкции есть и в середине, чем они "хуже"?

ВАШ ВОПРОС.  У присоединительных союзов особая функция,  они как бы не входят в грамматику самого предложения, то есть присоединяют данное предложение к контексту. Вот,  к примеру,  стоит деепричастный оборот в начале предложения.  Это аналог придаточного предложения, присоединительный союз ему не помешает. А теперь поставим запятую после союза. Теперь у оборота вставочная интонация, дополнительная актуализация и подчеркивание. А это  входит в замысел автора или нет?  Это ему решать.  Ну и структуру надо смотреть. А тут мы со своими правилами:  союз НО выделяется обязательно!

Об оформлении :) Вы часто пишете о красоте. Ну где же она на сером фоне? Против цвета ничего не имею, но на нём всё сплошным текстом, одним шрифтом, тем более что вы любите выделять значимые слова. А к цитированию нужно относиться более щепетильно (курсив в примерах и пр.). Что это за "и и но и"? //  Вопрос так и остался. Стык любых союзов, оборотов, вводных слов встречается после запятой, то есть после первой части ССП, СПП, и в таких случаях, мне кажется, должны применяться те же критерии выбора знаков, а они (критерии) прописаны не очень-то ясно.

Здесь есть возможность отделять свой текст от цитат. Этим многие пользуются, и я в том числе. Сразу понятно, где что.

Запятая не обязательна, но, видимо, считается что "но" относится к утверждению за деепричастным оборотом, если таковое имеется, а вот если нет далее иного утверждения, то запятая не нужна.

Сложный момент, запятая не всегда обязательна. Дело в том, что деепричастный оборот часто можно убрать без потери смысла:

Аскалон, не сжалясь над нею, но почувствовав скотское желание,
предприял, как возможно, стараться о приведении её в хорошее
состояние, послал на свой корабль за припасами и велел весьма скоро
изготовить хорошее кушанье. Чулков.

Очевидно можно выкинуть "почувствовав скотское желание" и делать это приходится с "но" раз нет запятой: "Аскалон, не сжалясь над нею, предприял...". Выкидываем второй деепричастный оборот: "Аксалон предпринял..." - все хорошо.
То есть "но почувствовав скотское желание" относилось к блоку "не сжалясь над нею, но почувствовав скотское желание" - тут запятая не нужна.\
Однако, если рассуждать, что запятая нужна, то получится, что "но" относится к "предпринял". Выкидываем деепричастные обороты, получаем: "Аксалон(,) но предпринял" - некорректно.
То есть, Чулков не поставил запятую и был абсолютно прав.
Но(,) зная это, трудно поверить его словам.
Я бы тут поспорил вообще над обособлением деепричастного оборота, потому что он входит как обязательное условие трудности, не просто трудно, а "зная это - трудно".
Поверить его словам легко, но зная это - трудно поверить его словам.
Поверить его словам было легко, но, зная это, я решил, мне трудно поверить его словам.
Вообще, фраза странная, потому что деепричастие или деепричастный оборот + инфинитив. Или точнее деепричастие+местоимение+наречие+глагол, такие конструкции вообще запятыми не всегда разбиваются:

...как бы желая тем еще привязать ее к суетам мира! Карамзин.
Здесь они оставили философа, пожелав ему благополучно отправить свою
обязанность, и заперли за ним дверь, по приказанию пана. Гоголь.
Он с честию отпустил в Крым нового хана Девлет-гирея, наказывая ему
ненарушимо хранить мир с Россиею). Пушкин.
Липутин, кажется, и сам почувствовал, что слишком много взял на себя: совершив свой подвиг, он так опешил от собственной дерзости, что даже не уходил с эстрады и стоял, как будто желая что-то еще прибавить. Достоевский.
...он начал ей досаждать на каждой станции, подбегая к окну ее вагона и прося ее «серьезно» сказать ему: имеет ли она средство спасти его? Лесков.

Может быть, запятые вообще не нужны:
Но зная это трудно поверить его словам?
В общем, именно деепричастие+..+инфинитив часто не обособляются. А вот если будет НЕ+деепричастие+..+инфинитив, то деепричастие с отрицанием обособляется:
Но, не зная это, трудно поверить его словам.
Хотя нет, наверное, тут всё-таки нужна запятая хотя бы одна, потому что можно разложить на подчинительную конструкцию:
Но когда это знаешь, тогда поверить его словам трудно. - то есть тут нет цельности, как в примерах без запятой, и скорее больше походит на пример Чулкова, несмотря на инфинитив.
Но когда почувствовал желание, тогда предпринял.
То есть, должна быть общность между всеми словами подобного оборота. Иначе нужна запятая:
Но зная это, трудно поверить его словам./Но, зная это, трудно поверить его словам.

Спасибо! Чуть позже напишу комментарий подробнее.


Но(,) зная это, трудно поверить его словам. Неужели будем обязательно ставить запятую, обособляя оборот. Как на практике ставятся знаки в нераспространенных
предложениях?

◉ На практике указанная короткая деепричастная конструкция обособляется в любом месте предложения в восьми случаях из девяти (см. Нацкорпус — но зная это; эх, 1835 год не вписался!):
Но, зная это, Артем ничего не мог нарисовать в воображении... (Роман Сенчин. Елтышевы (2008) // «Дружба Народов», 2009);
Так было у меня и с вами, я как бы знал заранее, что ничего у меня не получится, но, зная это, я с восторгом смотрел на дорогу, по которой вы проходили... (Анатолий Ким. Белка (1984));
Но, зная это, он не должен был этого делать (Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина (1878)).
◉ На практике другой коротенький оборот обособляется в пяти случаях из шести (См. Нацкорпус — но сказав это):
...пробормотал Антоша вроде бы в микрофон, вроде бы в зал, но, сказав это, тут же правым оком повернулся к столу президиума, то есть к самому глумильщику (Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007));
— Но, сказав это, Кузнецов заметил оробелый, ставший пришибленным взгляд Чибисова... (Юрий Бондарев. Горячий снег (1969));
— Идем! — Но, сказав это, он остановился. — Не позвать ли еще Адриана? — предложил он (М. Н. Волконский. Гамлет XVIII века (1903)).
⤟ ⤠   ⤟ ⤠ ⤟ ⤠   ⤟ ⤠   ⤟ ⤠   ⤟ ⤠  ⤟ ⤠   ⤟ ⤠   ⤟ ⤠  ⤟ ⤠   ⤟ ⤠  ⤟ ⤠

Примечание. Меня особенно огорчают всякого рода перестановки при анализе. Союз относится ко всему предложению и стоит в его начале, так что не надо его переставлять))

◉ "Дык" никто союз-то и не трогал! В вопросе, который вы приводите в ссылке, переставлялся деепричастный оборот, а не союз.
Но, долго находясь на чужбине, чувствуешь, что хочется домой. — Но чувствуешь, долго находясь на чужбине, что хочется домой.
Жаль, что вы огорчились, но, следуя правилу Розенталя, я вправе была именно так сделать.
◉ После "но" надо ставить запятую.
Всё остальное на сегодня — глубоко авторская пунктуация или страстное желание избавиться от якобы лишних запятых.

Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения)... [Розенталь])
Деепричастный оборот, находящийся после союза или союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (союзы не включаются в деепричастный оборот)... [Лопатин]


Мне кажется, там проблема в конструкции деепричастие+..+инфинитив, именно такие конструкции не обособляются, а идут целиком. Но если НЕ есть у деепричастия или глагола в инфинитиве, то обособление будет.

Комментарий к ответу
Спасибо нашему уважаемому участнику @Буратино за ответ и интересные примеры.
Тема расширена (в вопросе я имела в виду только присоединительный союз НО в начале предложения), но так даже лучше. И я попробую разобрать приведённые примеры. У меня немного другой метод анализа (я обычно ничего не убираю и не переставляю), но это не принципиально.
(1) Аскалон, не сжалясь над нею, но почувствовав скотское желание, предпринял, как возможно, стараться о приведении её в хорошее состояние, послал на свой корабль за припасами и велел весьма скоро изготовить хорошее кушанье. Чулков.
Здесь обособлена сложная деепричастная конструкция (блок), составленная  по схеме противопоставления НЕ...НО (вариант НЕ...А). Частица НЕ и союз НО относятся к деепричастным оборотам. Блок обособляется как единое целое, а внутри его ставится запятая. Можно убрать весь обособленный блок, и грамматика останется корректной. И это интересный пример того, как союз НО включается в оборот.

Но(,) зная это, трудно поверить его словам.

Предложение я по ходу придумала сама, чтобы не искать)
Оно получилось интересным, так как это тема галлицизмов (она недавно разбиралась на форуме). Вроде бы здесь безличное предложение, а ему не положено иметь деепр. оборот, но там есть инфинитив, и тогда грамматика считается корректной.
Но зная это, трудно поверить его словам.  Нет причин вообще не обособлять оборот. Эту семантику можно выразить иначе: Но при отсутствии этого знания  / трудно поверить его словам (здесь нет ни одной запятой, а смысл тот же).
Но, не зная это, трудно поверить его словам. Допустим, но не факт)
3.Присоединительный союз относится по смыслу ко всему предложению,  но мы можем присоединить его к обороту и обособить всю конструкцию. Если же поставить запятую после НО, то будет обособлен один оборот и выделен паузами с двух сторон, то есть подчеркнут. При этом  необходимость в подчеркивании зависит от контекста, и это авторский выбор. А правила лишают его такого выбора.

Некоторые конструкции

...как бы желая тем еще привязать ее к суетам мира!
Карамзин.
Липутин, кажется, и сам почувствовал, что слишком много взял на себя: совершив свой подвиг, он так опешил от собственной дерзости, что даже не уходил с эстрады и стоял, как будто желая что-то еще прибавить. Достоевский. Сравнительные союзы входят в оборот, а правилах этого нет.
...он начал ей досаждать на каждой станции, подбегая к окну ее вагона и прося ее «серьезно» сказать ему: имеет ли она средство спасти его? Лесков.  Однородные деепричастные обороты соединены союзом И.

У меня еще такая версия — часто действует структурный принцип. Если оборот с союзом НО удобно писать и произносить слитно, а семантика не важна, то ни к чему обособлять оборот с двух сторон.


Все-таки мне хотелось бы понять точку зрения людей, когда одни готовы принять правила по этой теме безоговорочно и всегда следовать им, а другие допускают варианты.
Поэтому я предлагаю решить небольшую задачу,  в которой надо выбрать постановку запятой после НО перед придаточным предложением и деепричастным оборотом. Контекст есть, поставлено авторское логическое ударение.
(1) Прежде чем заняться новой темой, хорошо подумайте, стоит ли это делать. Но(?) если нАчали, доведите ее до концА.
(2) Прежде чем заняться новой темой, хорошо подумайте, стоит ли это делать. Но(?) начАв ее, доведите до концА.
Как вы решите задачу и объясните свое решение?
7 июля 2024 года
К сожалению, желающих решить задачу не нашлось, и я закрываю тему с пожеланием: не стоит укладывать русское письмо в прокрустово ложе однозначности.
А это "объяснение" от желающих это сделать непременно:
 После НО надо ставить запятую. Всё остальное на 
 сегодня — глубоко авторская пунктуация или 
 страстное желание избавиться от якобы лишних 
 запятых.

Я так и не получила ответ на свой вопрос: почему  союз НО всегда следует отделять от деепричастного оборота, хотя, казалось бы, ничего не мешает наличию ВАРИАНТОВ. Писатель может видеть разные решения, и не стоит ограничивать его жестким и малопонятным правилом. Особенно если это правило НИКТО не может объяснить.
А также  если в предложении из 5 слов будет стоять 4 запятые тоже)) Как это прочитать? Это уже ваше дело! Главное, чтобы по правилам все было. Интонационный принцип пунктуации для этих людей не закон, а запятые — это всего лишь графические знаки, которые нужны для унификации письма.
 Прокрустово ложе — мерка, под которую стремятся 
 насильственно подогнать, приспособить то, что не 
 подходит под нее. Выражение из античной мифологии. 
 Прокруст Полипомен, сын Нептуна, разбойник и 
 истязатель, ловил прохожих и клал их на свое ложе. 
 Тем, у кого ноги были длиннее ложа, он обрубал их, 
 а тем, у кого они были короче, - вытягивал, 
 подвешивая к ногам тяжести.


Но у  меня все же есть ВЕРСИЯ ОТВЕТА.

Мы видели из приведенного в ответах примера, что союз НО может соединяться с деепричастным оборотом:

Аскалон, НЕ сжалясь над нею, НО почувствовав скотское желание, предпринял, как возможно, стараться о приведении её в хорошее состояние...
Здесь обособлена сложная деепричастная конструкция (блок), составленная по схеме противопоставления НЕ...НО (вариант НЕ...А). Частица НЕ и союз НО относятся к деепричастным оборотам.
И такие варианты могут встречаться в текстах,
например:
Г. С. Зеленина,2014
Впрочем, не до конца пожертвовав, а так: очень отважно рискнув, но оставшись в живых.

А вот перед одиночным обособленным оборотом в середине предложения союз НО  не включается в оборот,  так как он относится к структуре предложения. Такой вариант встречается чаще, например:  Захлопнув дверь на щеколду, наконец-то остался один, но, оставшись, не знал, что делать. Об этом варианте говорится в правилах.

По семантике присоединительный союз НО относится к предыдущему тексту, а по грамматике ко всему предложению, в построении структуры самого предложения он не участвует.  Тем не менее ПРОСТОТЫ РАДИ в базовом варианте действует общее правило, которое ни к семантике, ни к произношению отношения не имеет. И вот это правило  условно считается обязательным для всех случаев, так как анализ здесь сложнее.


Такова моя версия на текущий момент, пока не предложат другой вариант объяснения.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ от 08.07.2024 г.
Интересно такое наблюдение. Актуализация оборота обычно делается при значении причины (но так как), например:
Я не могу сказать, что я с охотой выбрал себе профессию кожевника, но, оставшись вновь безработным, мне было не до выбора желательной профессии. Ошибка,кстати)), галлицизм!
Л. М. Каганович. Памятные записки (1991)
Но в значении но когда запятая чаще не ставится:
Но оставшись без нее, вдруг затосковали — поняли, что без ее обильной безоглядной любви стало им одиноко и грустно.
Но оставшись без кормильца, семья сплотилась и выстояла.
Но оставшись в одиночестве, я надеялся на литературу.
